# how to downgrade from Rails 3.1.1 to Rails 3.0.3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I created an App in Rails 3.1.1 but now I want to downgrade it to Rails 3.0.3. Will replacing rails version in gemfile do given the new file structure of Rails 3.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will have to get rid of asset pipeline (maybe something else). If you haven't gone far, it might be easier to just regenerate the app.

Comment: I have few gem dependencies issue. Do you know how to use two version of gem in same app?

Comment: @BhushanLodha: No, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

The major change is the assents folder. Transfer the data into public folder for 3.0